# ModuleNotFoundError while running pytest from cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm running a `pytest` test with cmd (from a .bat file) and getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`.
But when running it from PyCharm, it works fine.
I looked around and saw some solutions regarding `PYTHONPATH` but that doesn't seem to work.
Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running:

```
$ python -m pytest /test/...
```

Instead of `$ pytest /test/...` you can find more on it in pytest [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/pythonpath.html#pytest-vs-python-m-pytest)

Comment: Yes, still not working though